# How to detach newsboat rss reader from terminal when open external browser?

Tags: linux, terminal

The last few days I've tried use [Newsboat](https://newsboat.org/), a terminal RSS reader. It has the option for open an article with external browser (like Firefox), but when open the article Newsboat is attached on process and is impossible use it until close Firefox.

Neswboat has a config file, in there I put the next line:

```
browser "/usr/bin/firefox-esr %u &"
```

The setting works but if I close Firefox on terminal appears a error message related with a pipe error, and if I quit Newsboat when close Firefox appears the same message and propmt is freeze and I have to type Ctrl+C. So, my solution is a partial solution.

I read the official [documentation](https://newsboat.org/releases/2.20.1/docs/newsboat.html) but I can't find something for help. Maybe you can help me.

Comment: Try redirecting firefox's output somewhere `browser "/usr/bin/firefox-esr %u >>$HOME/firefox-junk 2>&1 &"`. Firefox writes a lot of annoying debugging garbage to stderr, maybe your rss reader tries to "collect" it.

Comment: Thanks @user414777 but the same weird out message. I have another similar tip here: https://superuser.com/a/178592. Anyhow, I achieve detach so I move on with this problem.

Comment: Try using `browser "setsid firefox-esr %u ..."` in addition to backgrounding and redirections. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Bad news, with  `setsid` the error message keeps on screen, overlaping the terminal text.